# Trying to assign imageview tag in cell an index number. Always gets assign 7, the last visible cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that list videos from the user's library. When the user taps on the image view, I want the video to play on a new view controller.

I'm having a problem where all of my imageviews' 'tag' property in the cells are being assigned with the number 7, the last visible cell. When I scroll all of the gets assign a different number. Can you guys help me figure out the problem?

I'm getting the correct image for the asset based on ' let asset = assets[indexPath.row]' and 'requestImageForAsset', so I'm not sure why indexPath.row is not working in this case.

I'm using the imageview tag to find the video in an array from the table view.

The custom cell:

```
  class VideoCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var screenShot: UIImageView!
}
```

the View Controller:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
   return assets.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCell
    let asset = assets[indexPath.row]

    imageManager!.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil) { (result, _ ) in

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? VideoCell {
            cell.screenShot.image = result
            cell.screenShot.tag = indexPath.row
        }
    }
    return cell
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "VideoPlayer" {
        if let playerVC = segue.destinationViewController as? AVPlayerVC {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {playerVC.player = self.player}
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func videoImageTapped(sender: AnyObject) { 
    let view = sender.view
    let index = view!!.tag
    let asset = assets[index]

    imageManager!.requestPlayerItemForVideo(asset, options: nil) { (playerItem, info) -> Void in
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("VideoPlayer", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll actually want to change this to use a didSelectRowAtIndexPath method if a user can select a whole cell, if they need to select a button then you should create a custom cell class with the button inside the cell.

Then you can pass your current index in the button's tag to a method outside of the cellForAtIndexPath method.

On second thought, here's how you can do it with a tap gesture recognizer.

Create a sub class of a UITapGestureRecognizer and add a tag property. In your custom cell create an instance variable of the custom tap gesture recognizer type, in the awakeFromNib of the custom cell add the custom recognizer to the image view (set the image view to user interaction = true as well).

Back in your view controller with the table view assign the indexPath.row to the cell's new gesture recognizer tag property. Then add a target to the cell's custom gesture recognizer property.

In the target method add a sender parameter as the custom tap gesture recognizer (or AnyObject) and grab the .tag property to get your index.

Comment: Yeah, I know a button makes more sense, but I originally had a UIImageView. Now that the functionality has changed a bit, I wanted to it to be tappable, so I added a gesture recognizer. 

Everything works as correctly now that I tested it with a button and assigned it's tag to the cell index.  I just don't understand why it isn't working with an imageView tag.

Comment: Where was the gesture recognizer instantiated and assigned to the imageView? I think you got 7 in the tag b/c of cell re-use. Using something that's contained in the cell will give you the properties for any given cell or any object that you're using it's indexPath with.

Comment: Bear with me, this also my first time working with Storyboard. But yeah, I dragged a tapGestureRecognizer on to the imageView.

Comment: No problem, so you had a tap gesture recognizer on the image view that was in your custom cell but the action for the gesture recognizer existed in your view controller? Maybe just create the tap gesture recognizer inside the custom cell's file, then add a target to it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.